# How to Change the Image of Cell Selected in ipad app

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I am using tableView with custom cell i want that when user select any row it show selected image on that here is code but it does not show selected image

Here is the code i am using custom cell for this tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";
    cell = (RootCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CustomCellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"RootCell"
                                                     owner:self options:nil];
        for(id oneObject in nib) {
            if ([oneObject isKindOfClass:[RootCell class]]) {
                cell = (RootCell *)oneObject;
                cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
            }
        }
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ActivityF.png"];  
    } else if(indexPath.row==1) {
        cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CatalogF.png"];
    } else if(indexPath.row==2){
        cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"LibraryF.png"];  
    } else if(indexPath.row==3) {
        cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"CommunityF.png"]; 
    } else if (indexPath.row==4) {
        cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"ReportsF.png"];
    } else if (indexPath.row==5) {
        cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PublishingF.png"];
    } else if (indexPath.row==6) {
        cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"PostsF.png"];    
    } else {
        cell.cellImageView=[UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"];  
    }

    UIImageView *separator = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"separatorline.png"]];
    [cell.contentView addSubview: separator];

    return cell;

    self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(149/255.f) green:(150/255.f) blue:(149/255.f) alpha:1.0f];
}
```

did Select Method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSUInteger row = indexPath.row;
    [self.appDelegate.splitViewController viewWillDisappear:YES];
    NSMutableArray *viewControllerArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:    [[self.appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1] viewControllers]];
    [viewControllerArray removeLastObject];
    if (row == 0) {
        self.firstDetailViewController=[[[FirstDetailViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.firstDetailViewController];
        self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.firstDetailViewController; }

    if (row == 1) {
        self.secondDetailViewController=[[[SecondDetailViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.secondDetailViewController];
        self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.secondDetailViewController;
    }

    if (row == 2) {
        self.myLearningViewController=[[[MyLearningViewController alloc]init]autorelease];
        [viewControllerArray addObject:self.myLearningViewController];
        self.appDelegate.splitViewController.delegate = self.myLearningViewController;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
RootCell *cell = (RootCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImage.png"];
```

Comment: I think that should be cell.imageView

Comment: Also make sure you add cell.imageView = nil for all cells are not selected

Comment: but i have different selection images for differect rows like in code how will add

Comment: I am not asking you the provide code i also got working the cell image but i asked that for every cell selected previous one should show old image not selected

Answer (score 0):

In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method

```
 RootCell *cell = (RootCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];


    if (indexPath.row == 0) {

    cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImagecell1.png"];

}
else if(indexPath.row==1){

    cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImagecell2.png"];

}

else if(indexPath.row==2){

    cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImagecell3.png"];

}

else if(indexPath.row==3){

    cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImagecell4.png"];

}

else if(indexPath.row==4){

    cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImagecell5.png"];

}

else if(indexPath.row==5) {

    cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImagecell6.png"];

}

else if (indexPath.row==6){

    cell.cellImageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedImagecell7.png"];

    }

else {
    cell.cellImageView=[UIImage imageNamed:@"other.png"];

 }
```

Comment: it works but when i select any cell it gets new image but when i select new cell previous one also show new image previous one should not show now the selected image